# How to pass parameters in Jmeter for username and login.?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have just been assigned the tasks of doing some research and doing some JMeter tests for performance testing. As I have never used this tool before.!

I just added the IP or address of my project, in that screen there is two textbox for username and password lets say its id are User1 / Pass1. I'm having several authenticate credentials to check. so how can i parameter those from an external sheet.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular approach to provide external data to parametrize JMeter tests is [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **User Parameter** Pre-processor.
You can add variable with name value pair in this pre-processor.
For e.g. : 
name : id value : abc
name : pwd value : xyz

you can then refer these variables in your samplers as ${id} & ${pwd}

Also you can increase the users count just by adding more users.

See below image for more details.

[image]